# 302 Redirect Originates from ASP.NET or IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-302

Is it possible to work out whether a redirect occurred from something setup within IIS, or whether an ASP.NET application issued the redirect for IIS to perform?

I have an ASP.NET site which is redirecting a HTTPS page to HTTP page (which I don't want it do do), and which I have confirmed by the following headers:

```
https://***.co.uk/MainWebsite/Intro.aspx

GET /MainWebsite/Intro.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: ***.co.uk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1422039573.1457307455; ASP.NET_SessionId=bazsdsfsdfrre0vp30joy
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://***.co.uk/MainWebsite/Intro.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:04:13 GMT
Content-Length: 184
```

Do the "X-AspNet-Version" and "X-Powered-By" headers suggest that ASP.NET have told IIS to do a redirect, or is it impossible to tell from this information?

Thanks